# PhpStorm different comments colors based on custom conditions

Tags: phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

I would like to have a few different colors of same comment method, based on my own conditions. For example in twig comments, if comment starts with ! sign, I would like to make this comment different color then rest:

```
{# regular gray color #}
{#! special green color #}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Sure -- write your own plugin that will replace existing one and will parse the code and decide what style to apply. Otherwise -- it's not possible.